# 'Ticks' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This my code:

```
 var count = this.Repository.ObjectContext.LogDetail
                .Count(p => p.LogId == logId &&System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions. p.LogDetailTime. == logDetailTime.Ticks && p.OperationId == operationId);
            return (count > 0);
```

and i get this error:

> The specified type member 'Ticks' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

How can i resolve it?

Comment: Why not just use `p.LogDetailTime == logDetailTime`? Do the types not match?

Answer (score 6):

As said, you should not fetch all records into memory and then do the filtering. You can easily compare the date values without converting to ticks:

```
var query = this.Repository.ObjectContext.LogDetail
            .Where(p => p.LogId == logId 
                     && p.OperationId == operationId
                     && EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(p.LogDetailTime,
                                                      logDetailTime) == 0);
return (query.Any());
```

Note that `DiffSeconds` can cause an overflow when the difference becomes larger than `Int32.MaxValue` (Error: *The datediff function resulted in an overflow*). I don't know what precision you're after and how far the compared values are apart, so you have to make a choice here. Were you really interested in records with exactly the same amount of ticks? Hard to imagine. Maybe `DiffMinutes` is good enough.

Another possible optimization is to use `Any` in stead of `Count`. `Any` generates an `WHERE EXISTS` clause. This may be more efficient than `COUNT` in SQL.

What you gain is that now only a boolean (bit) is transferred in stead of a potentially large number of records.

---

**Note**: In Entity Framework 6 `EntityFunctions` has been replaced by [`DbFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffseconds%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Comment: I have the overflow problem and I can't get away from it. I have to check for diff greater than 30 seconds for diffs in the years range. I know in SQL I could convert the dates to DECIMAL first then do the comparison, but I can't find a way to do that with EF. For now I have to do the query in two parts: one which filters greater than a month, then I do another query that includes the remaining reconds and filtering with seconds. It's a bit ugly I must say.

Answer (score 2):

This happens a lot with LINQ to Entities when using some method/property that cannot be used inside the database.

In that case, you can put the value of it inside a variable.

I've noticed that you have a syntax error too, but you can fix it. The following code should be work after you'll fix that syntax error around `System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions. p.LogDetailTime.`

```
var ticks = logDetailTime.Ticks;
var count = this.Repository.ObjectContext.LogDetail
            .Count(p => p.LogId == logId &&System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions. p.LogDetailTime. == ticks && p.OperationId == operationId);
        return (count > 0);
```