# Entity Framework Sum DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, entity-framework-6

I have the following query that calculates a total duration. The total duration is subtraction between StartingDate and EndingDate (StartingDate - EndingDate):

```
var v = from m in db.PageRequests
        group m by m.SiteSession into g
        select new
        {
            totalDuration = g.Key.PageRequests.Where(x => x.EndingDate.HasValue).Sum(x => x.EndingDate.Value.Ticks - x.StartingDate.Value.Ticks)
        };
```

As the Sum function returns a number (int) I thought to use DateTime.**Ticks** but then it thrown the following exception:

> The specified type member 'Ticks' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I saw some solutions with `EntityFunctions` and `DbFunctions` but they work on a specific time scope (days, minutes etc). I need it in any time scope (might be milliseconds, seconds, hours, days etc).

Comment: Well, you can just pick a small time precision, such as milliseconds and sum those, then do math on it later.  However, that's only going to work for hours and smaller.  As soon as you get into days, you'll have to recall that not every local day is 24 hours long, due to DST transitions.  Similarly, not every month has the same number of days due to our calendar, and not every year has the same number of days due to leap years.  So one *can't* just have a generic total that works at any scale.

Comment: How about [DbFunctions.DiffNanoseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffnanoseconds(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffNanoseconds%28System.Nullable{System.DateTime},System.Nullable{System.DateTime}%29)?

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried this, it throws: "The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart."

Comment: @MattJohnson Is it possible to do this distinction in the query?

Comment: I would say continue trying - `Microseconds`, `Milliseconds` :)

Comment: I think `DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds` is enough. BTW, your problem is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726551/ticks-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities. Note that any `DbFunctions.Diff*` (* = every time unit) methods may cause overflow if the value is larger than `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @Jacob - no, not really.  You'll have to give it a different query if you want `DiffMonths` than you would if you want `DiffMinutes`.  Also, you might consider just writing a SQL stored procedure and calling that instead.

Comment: @MattJohnson Stored procedure is a good idea although I prefer to keep stick with the EF (CF) for simplicity. In the meantime, I just created two Sum() values, one for days and one for milliseconds. Then I take the days if it contains a value, otherwise I take the milliseconds. e.g: totalDurationMill = Sum(x => (x.EndingDate.Value.Millisecond - x.StartingDate.Value.Millisecond) and the other is: totalDurationDays.Sum(x => (x.EndingDate.Value.Day - x.StartingDate.Value.Day)). Thank you for giving me the idea to do so.